# Gradle: What's wrong with assignment `excludeGroups` for TestNG?

Tags: gradle, groovy

There are project where I used TestNG & Gradle. 
Test section from build.gradle file:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = true
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

/*
    some code there
*/

task integTest(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups = ['jt-someTest2', 'jt-someTest3'].toSet()
    }
}
```

For this case everithing works fine. But when I try some like this:

```
def allAvailableTestGroups = ['someTest1', 'someTest2', 'someTest3'].toSet()
def testGroup = project.hasProperty("testGroup") ? project.testGroup : 'all'


tasks.withType(Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = true
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

/*
    ...
    some code there
    ...
*/

task integTest(type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups = ( allAvailableTestGroups.collect { "jt-${it}" }.findAll { it != testGroup } ) as HashSet<String>
    }
}
```

I got such trouble:

> org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
>           //...
>  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
>           //...
>  Unexpected exception thrown.
>  org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not read
>   message from '/127.0.0.1:58219'.
>           //...
>  Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.io.IOException: ╙фрыхээ√щ їюёЄ яЁшэєфшЄхы№эю ЁрчюЁтры
>   ёє∙хёЄтє■∙хх яюфъы■ўхэшх
>           //...
>  Caused by: java.io.IOException: ╙фрыхээ√щ їюёЄ яЁшэєфшЄхы№эю ЁрчюЁтры ёє∙хёЄтє■∙хх яюфъы■ўхэшх
>           //...
>  Unexpected exception thrown.
>  org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not
>   write '/127.0.0.1:58219'.
>           //...
>  Caused by: java.io.IOException: ╙фрыхээ√щ їюёЄ яЁшэєфшЄхы№эю ЁрчюЁтры ёє∙хёЄтє■∙хх яюфъы■ўхэшх
>           //...
>  :integTest FAILED
>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

**What's wrong?**

Comment: You should ask your question on https://discuss.gradle.org/ too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
excludeGroups = ( allAvailableTestGroups.collect { "jt-${it}" }
    .findAll { it != testGroup } ) as HashSet<String>
```

With this:

```
excludeGroups = ( allAvailableTestGroups.collect { "jt-${it}".toString() }
    .findAll { it != testGroup } ) as Set
```

Looks like the Groovy compiler is missing the auto-translation of your GString `"jt-$it"` for some reason... calling `toString()` should fix that.